# Check if oe specific user is online

Tags: wordpress

is there any way, to check, if one specific user is online in Wp?

Comment: Programmatically, as part of a plugin, or manually?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful:

- [WordPress How To Check If User Already Logged In](http://www.bala-krishna.com/wordpress-how-to-check-if-user-already-logged-in/)